# Changing the turtlesim environment colors

Tags: ros, c++, turtlebot, turtlesim, ros-tutorials

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does anyone know how to change the turtlesim environment (background color and turtle line/pen color) in a C++ program?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12805/changing-the-turtlesim-environment-colors./) by [Index](https://answers.ros.org/users/1702/index/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-01-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

These features are documented at http://www.ros.org/wiki/turtlesim  There is the setPen service which lets you up and down, as well as change the pen color.

The background color is parameterized, but likely is only read at startup.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-01-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1